# .Net 5 Windows and Custom Auth

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm writing a Razor Pages application running on .Net 5.0. This application needs to be able to support members of staff (who sign in with Windows authentication) and applicants (who don't have a Windows account, so need to register/login with a custom authentication process). I can either get Windows auth or custom auth to work, but the two don't want to play ball together!!

I believe I need to write a custom implementation of `IAuthenticationService` but this is where it's tripping me up. I can't work out what I need to do in `ChallengeAsync` in order to let the challenge pass!

Here's the AuthService implementation at the moment (yes, it's not the nicest, but my focus at this point is on getting it working!!):

```
    public class AuthService : IAuthenticationService
        {
            async Task<AuthenticateResult> IAuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme)
            {
                if (HasAnonymousAttribute(context))
                {
                    return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
                }
    
                var user = getUser(context);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(user, "magic");
                    return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
                }
    
    
                await context.ChallengeAsync("Windows");
    
                if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(context.User, "Windows");
                    return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
                }
    
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Please log in");
            }
    
            Task IAuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
            {
                var user = context.Session.Get("User");
                if (user == null)
                {
                    //do something to block the user from access
                }
    
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
    
            Task IAuthenticationService.ForbidAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    
            Task IAuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
            {
                if(scheme.ToLower() == "magic")
                {
                    context.Session.Set("User", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(principal.Identity.Name));
                }
    
                return Task.FromResult(0);
    
            }
    
            Task IAuthenticationService.SignOutAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    
            private ClaimsPrincipal getUser(HttpContext context)
            {
                if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    return (ClaimsPrincipal)context.User.Identity;
                }
                return null;
    
            }
    
            private bool HasAnonymousAttribute(HttpContext context)
            {
                var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
                var retVal = (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>() != null);
    
                return retVal;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement only the methods in which you need custom logic.

So instead of implementing the interface, you could subclass the regular Asp.Net `AuthenticationService`, then put custom logic in `AuthenticateAsync` but don't override `ChallengeAsync`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

namespace Some.Lovely.Namespace
{
    public class MyCustomAuthenticationService : AuthenticationService
    {
        public CustomAuthenticationService(
            [NotNull] IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes,
            [NotNull] IAuthenticationHandlerProvider handlers,
            [NotNull] IClaimsTransformation transform,
            [NotNull][ItemNotNull] IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> options) :
base(schemes, handlers, transform, options)
        { }

        public override async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, string? scheme)
        {
            // your custom logic
        }
    }
}
```

Then register the service like so in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, MyCustomAuthenticationService >();
```

Comment: Same technique as I'm using to override the AuthenticationService, although bizarrely some of the methods declared within AuthenticationService such as CreateMissingHandlerException are Private so you've no real option when overriding a virtual method to **re-implement** the private methods where re-use is needed (e.g., if you're just refactoring *some* of the original implementation logic).