# Multiple schemes not working when access a route with Role Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am working with an ASP.NET Core Web API which has the following configuration:

```
private static void ConfigureAuthorization(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    // Make sure every scheme is also registered in ConfigureAuthentication!
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
       {
           var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
               AuthenticationScheme.SESSION,
               AuthenticationScheme.BASIC,
               AuthenticationScheme.API_TOKEN
           );
           defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
               defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
           options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
       });
}

private static void ConfigureAuthentication(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    // Make sure every scheme is also registered in AddAuthorization!
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(AuthenticationScheme.SESSION)
           .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, SessionAuthenticationHandler>(AuthenticationScheme.SESSION, null)
           .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>(AuthenticationScheme.BASIC, null)
           .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, ApiTokenAuthenticationHandler>(AuthenticationScheme.API_TOKEN, null);
}
```

When I make a request with basic auth, I have the following situation

1. `[AllowAnonymous]` -> Ok
2. `[Authorize]` -> Ok
3. `[Authorize(Roles = "ExampleRole")]` -> exception

For the first two situations, all my auth handlers are triggered, so the basic auth will succeed. When I request against a role-based endpoint, I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Handle|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

If I add

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AuthenticationScheme.BASIC;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AuthenticationScheme.BASIC;
})
```

Then it will go into the basic handler. This isn't a solution though, as I need to support multiple handlers.

I read [.Net 5 Windows and Custom Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66240338/net-5-windows-and-custom-auth) and tried to inject the following as a scoped service:

```
public sealed class ChallengelessAuthenticationService : AuthenticationService
{
    public ChallengelessAuthenticationService(
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes, 
        IAuthenticationHandlerProvider handlers, 
        IClaimsTransformation transform, 
        IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> options) 
        : base(schemes, handlers, transform, options)
    {
    }

    public override Task ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, string? scheme, AuthenticationProperties? properties)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

However, with this solution the Authorize (Roles & No Roles) attribute stops working, and Unauthorized requests will be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddPolicyScheme` should be used as selector.

Source:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Mar/29/Combining-Bearer-Token-and-Cookie-Auth-in-ASPNET
https://archive.md/WDD2q

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // custom scheme defined in .AddPolicyScheme() below
    options.DefaultScheme = "JWT_OR_COOKIE";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JWT_OR_COOKIE";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
})
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = config.JwtToken.Issuer,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = config.JwtToken.Audience,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config.JwtToken.SigningKey))
    };
})
// this is the key piece!
.AddPolicyScheme("JWT_OR_COOKIE", "JWT_OR_COOKIE", options =>
{
    // runs on each request
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
    {
        // filter by auth type
        string authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer "))
            return "Bearer";

        // otherwise always check for cookie auth
        return "Cookies";
    };
});
```